# Iterate through SQLite DB Tuples not matching user input

Tags: python, sqlite, for-loop, input, tuples

I have a small database with one table named `cards`.

- Column `number` is `TEXT`.
- I have multiple rows and I am trying to get user input mach a row

For example:

```
    connection = sqlite3.connect('card.s3db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    card_check = cursor.execute('SELECT number FROM card')

    connection.commit()

    prompt_card_number = input("Enter your card number:\n")

    for number in card_check:
        if number == prompt_card_number:
            check_stage2()
    else:
        print("\nWrong card number or PIN!")

    connection.close()
```

For some reason I input the matching card number in the database but I still get `Wrong card number or PIN!` and I can't get through `check_stage2()`.
What am I doing wrong?

Edit: Ok so I tried this code now:

```
def check_stage1():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('card.s3db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT number FROM card')
    card_check = cursor.fetchall()
    print(card_check)

    prompt_card_number = input("Enter your card number:\n")

    for number in card_check:
        if number == prompt_card_number:
            # account_interface()
            print("ok")
    else:
        print("\nWrong card number or PIN!")

    connection.commit()
    connection.close()
```

And `card check` returns a list of weird tuples like this `[('4000006601632606',), ('4000006102182200',), ('4000009048898194',), ('4000006526735435',), ('4000002961735386',), ('4000008741268614',), ('4000001893515676',)]`
But I don't know how to iterate through it. It still doesn't seem to work if I input a correct number.

Edit 2:
I found out how to iterate through the tuples, but I still get `Wrong card number or PIN!` even if number[0] type is str, and my input is str as well. See this code:

```
def check_stage1():
    connection = sqlite3.connect('card.s3db')
    cursor = connection.cursor()

    cursor.execute('SELECT number FROM card')
    card_check = cursor.fetchall()
    print(card_check)

    prompt_card_number = input("Enter your card number:\n")

    for number in card_check:
        if number[0] == prompt_card_number:
            # account_interface()
            print(number[0])
            print(type(number[0]))
    else:
        print("\nWrong card number or PIN!")
```

Is returning `Enter your card number: 4000009048898194 <class 'str'>`
[image: descriptive image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some time I managed to solve this. All I had to do is figure out that I had to use `cursor.fetchall()` in order to dump the rows and I assigned it to a variable to see what it contains, it turns out it was a tuple list.

```
card_check = cursor.fetchall()
print(card_check)
```

From here I iterated over the list with a for loop selecting the index of the tuple, 0 like this:

```
    for number in card_check:
        if number[0] == prompt_card_number:
            print("ok")
            check_stage2()
            break
    else:
        print("\nWrong card number or PIN!")
```

Everything works fine now.

Answer (score 0):

`execute` returns a tuple, whether one column is selected or one hundred. `number` is not what you think it is in this sentence `if number == prompt_card_number:`

Comment: What sould I do? I figured its a tuple but after iterating over it its still prompting me with wrong card or pin even though I input the correct number.